# Converting object of type dtype='<U77' into numpy array

Tags: python

I have an object of `dtype='<U77'` type, consisting of a string of numbers, separated with the spaces:

```
array('[ 0.20988965  0.05172284 -0.13468404 ...  2.06070718 -0.6160391\n  3.        ]',
  dtype='<U77')
```

How can I convert it into numpy array?

Comment: Don't try and convert that.  You've got to fix the problem earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you wanted to do some kludgy string parsing to try to fix this object, you can't. You've already lost almost all of the original data, and there's no way to get it back just by looking at the string.

See that `...` in the middle? That's what happens when you `print` an array large enough to trigger summarization:

```
>>> print(numpy.arange(1001))
[   0    1    2 ...  998  999 1000]
```

It looks like you `print`ed a large array and then called `array` on the resulting string. NumPy isn't designed for `print` to be reversible, and even in the cases where it is reversible, calling `array` on the printed output isn't how you'd reverse it.

You need to redo the computation that originally produced the array, and pick a better way to save the result, like `numpy.save`.

Answer (score -2):

So here is a quick solution:

1. save the original data string as `np.savetxt('filename', data_string)`, then when loading you get something like the following:

   `array('[ 0.119871   -0.50688947  0.27891722  0.58804999 -2.03537473  0.63659631\n  1.2        -0.83374409 -1.04955507 -0.6538087  -0.05       -0.23323881\n  1.2         3.          1.2       ]', dtype='<U183')`
2. use `np.fromstring(c1[1:-2], dtype=float, sep=' ')` as a converter, this will come back with a similar numpy array:`array([ 0.119871  , -0.50688947,  0.27891722,  0.58804999, -2.03537473,
           0.63659631,  1.2       , -0.83374409, -1.04955507, -0.6538087 ,
          -0.05      , -0.23323881,  1.2       ,  3.        ,  1.2       ])`